# Update local notification while application is closed

Tags: objective-c

I have a notification that is displayed every 24 hours, but I need to check for changes in Core Data at least once per day in order to update it, preferably between 0:00 and 9:00.

If the app is used every day, I will have no problem. If a day is skipped then I will need to run that code in background.

I saw that people use `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`, but from what I understand it just executes the code after the application is closed, which not working for me.

So my question is what should I use to run some code periodically, when the application is closed, I think there was some way to ask the OS for some processor time.

Or is there a way to register my app to be called at 0:00 every day? Or any other solution?

Thank you!

P.S. I don't have any code written yet, except registering the notification.

Comment: Couldn't you run your checking code when app is closing/entering background? You can schedule single notification for next day, and if the app is launched during that day, reschedule next one.

Comment: @Rado whatever you are looking for it can be achieved via Silent Push Notification, which awakes ur app to do small task.

Comment: @brigadir Yes I can do that, but then the problem will be when the app is not oped for a long period, lets say 2 days. Then the closing/entering background will not be called on the 2nd day.

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara Thank you I will read on that.

Comment: @Rado, does your app data depend on back-end or it's completely offline? If offline, you can check your Core Data when the app is entering background (like predictive way) and be sure that the data will not be changed while the app is inactive.

Comment: @brigadir I am also doing that, running my code on `applicationWillResignActive`. But if the user doesn't enter the app for a week, I still want to get the notifications updated. Thats why I find the need to use Silent Push Notifications too. But once again it is completely offline data I need to use.